# How to take value from nested array

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time selecting the price_change of this array.

I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
response.data[0].[1d].price_change
```

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

```
    var stockDiff = document.getElementById("stockDiffCrypto");
    var thePrice = response.data[0].["1d"].price_change;

if (thePrice > 0) {
    stockDiff.innerHTML = `<i class='fas fa-angle-double-up'></i>`
    stockDiff.style.color = "green"
} else {
    stockDiff.innerHTML = `<i class='fas fa-angle-double-down'></i>`
    stockDiff.style.color = "red"
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? What happens if you put quotes around "1d": `response.data[0].["1d"].price_change`? The way you have it now, it's probably trying to evaluate the variable `1d`.

Comment: I'm getting console error: (Uncaught SyntaxError: missing name after . operator). As well in the script, after response.data[0]. I'm getting error TS1003: (JS) identifier expected

Comment: I just fixed.         var thePrice = response.data[0]["1d"].price_change;

Answer (score 2):

`variable.["property"]` is not valid syntax. These 2 are valid:

```js
variable.property
variable["property"]
```

This is the same with arrays

```js
array[0][0]
```

In your case it should be this

```js
var thePrice = response.data[0]["1d"].price_change
```