# React JS access object attribute using "." and variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, attributes

today at work a friend show me a strange way to access an object attribute using a variable.

To make it simple to understand, first we define an object, then a variable with a key of this object as string, then we try to access this key on the object.

```
object = {"123": 1, "12":2}
key = "12"
console.log(object[key])
```

this would return 2 and is the right way to do.

So my friend was doing this on react

```
object = {"123": 1, "12":2}
key = "12"
console.log(object.[key])
```

Trying this code on webbrowser console, returns error, but on React it works.

Can someone tell me why????
I'm really curious to know why this no sense code works

ready snippet to try on pure js

https://jsfiddle.net/ozgvfw02/1/

Comment: console.log(object[key])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487330/15781079 - you either use dot notation (`.`) or bracket notation (`[]`). You can't use both for accessing a single property

Comment: Just tried this in a react project... Errors out with immediate syntax error. You sure there wasn't an array, with a ? after the array variable name? Optional chaining could be used for this... Something like `arr?.[index]`